# ld: library 'System' not found when trying to compile

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors

Im trying to compile a dot object file as part of a tutorial. I've followed the command exactly

`ld -o exit_code.x exit_code.o -lSystem -syslibroot 'xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path'`

I get the following error:

`ld: library 'System' not found when trying to compile.`